# Is Windows 7 machine logged into domain or local cache

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller

I've been learning AD and also troubleshoot a problem I'm having with AD.  I'd like to be able to tell if a Windows 7 workstation is actively logged on to a domain or if it's logging into an account using locally cached credentials.
To test if this works I logged into a user account on a domain named **grasstree.void**.  Then powered off the domain controller. I then restarted my Windows 7 machine and logged into the domain.  I verified that Window computeres isn't on the network.  It has IP 169.254.95.63 and the AD server is powered off.  I then used the following methods, which gave me result that were indistinguishable from when the AD serer was on.

**Control Panel > System**

Shows me on **glasstree.void**

**C:\Users\jonnytest>whoami**

glasstree\jonnytest

**C:\Users\jonnytest>set logon**

LOGONSERVER=MASTERCONTROLLE

**C:\Users\jonnytest>gpresult /r**

...shows same as when on the domain controller.

So, how can I tell if I've logged in using the domain controller, or if I've logged in using the local cache.

Comment: Have you given any thought to disabling cached logons for stationary domain members?  That may alleviate the need to even ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to query the security event log for the event id 4264 event, which includes the logon type. Type 11 is cached interactive logon. (This also implies auditing must be enabled).

https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4624

Comment: Wow.  So there's no way for an average user find that information in Control Panel or System?  That seems ridiculous.